# Faces messages not shown after replacing navigation case by implicit navigation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I removed the navigation cases from `faces-config.xml` and switched to implicit navigation.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Datacenter " + ndc.componentStatsId + " is created!"));

if (result == 1)
{
    return "DatacentersList.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}

if (result == 2)
{
    return "NewDatacenter.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
return null;
```

The navigation is working very well, but it turns out that faces messages are not displayed anymore. How is this caused and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faces messages are request scoped. They are added to the current request. A redirect instructs the browser to create a **brand new** GET request on given URL. That new request is not the same as the current request. That new request does not contain those faces messages at all.

You have 2 options:

1. Do not redirect. You was likely also not redirecting in your original navigation cases.

   ```
   if (result == 1) {
       return "DatacentersList.xhtml";
   }

   if (result == 2) {
       return "NewDatacenter.xhtml";
   }
   ```
2. [Keep](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setKeepMessages%28boolean%29) the messages in the flash scope. The flash scope lives effectively as long as a single redirect.

   ```
   context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
   ```

   Note that older Mojarra versions had some peculiar bugs related to this. E.g redirect to a different folder would still cause it to fail. Make sure that you're using at least Mojarra version 2.1.14 to ensure that you won't be bothered by those bugs (it's currently already at 2.1.20).

Comment: Note that whether to perform a forward or a redirect is a functionally relatively huge difference which should carefully be decided based on the functional requirements. For instance, do you want the response to be idempotent/bookmarkable? What do you want to happen when the enduser refreshes the landing page by F5? Or when the enduser copypastes/bookmarks the current URL (as appears in browser's addressbar) and re-opens it? Or when the enduser navigates back to it through browser history? This is not a decision which should be carelessly made.